# Detecting screenshot on 4.0+ android devices

Tags: android, security, screenshot, detect

I have an application in which I want to be able to detect if a screenshot has been taken. The only way of doing this I could find involved utilizing a file observer. Is there any library which tackles this problem yet?

Alternatively, if I write my own library and use the file observer I need to be aware of the many different locations for screenshots on different devices. Is there a place where I can find a comprehensive list of these locations?

I am fully aware that this will not be 100% secure.

Comment: why you need to do that?

Comment: I am attempting to implement a feature similar to one that snapchat has. Where another user of the app will be notified of a screenshot attempt.

Comment: I don't know exactly how this can be done, but I know that the developers of Telegram have done just that and the application's source is available on GitHub: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check it out then.